# Infinite scroll using firebase realtime databse

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, infinite-scroll

I am working on android app and I am using Firebase realtime database to store my data. I want to add infinite scroll functionality to my app which loads data in different `batches`.

Firebase does not have an API which returns data in different batches. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Did you success infinite scroll with single batch?

Comment: Yes, however I am using firebase the function `onEventListner`. I dont think firebase allows to get read only data. I need something which gives read only data not an event listner.

Answer (score -1):

1) You'll need Arraylist and have to make your own CustomAdapter and set it to the recyclerview or listview.

2) Make multiple queries and retrieve the data for this you can make functions for each batches

3) add the data in Arraylist when scrolling is about to bottom .In this way you'll get infinite scrolls